# Where is Mail login info saved?

Tags: mail.app

After I upgraded macOSX to a new version, when I open Mail, it will start importing emails. I don't want it to import emails. But I don't know where the previous login info is saved (so that I can delete it). Does anybody know?

Comment: Probably from your iCloud credentials.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This shows absolutely no research or effort. Hint: Look in the prefs.

Comment: I will answer, but in the future if you search for an answer and then document that search we won’t answer with an article you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Credentials on macOS are generally stored in the keychain.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac

Once you clean that up, you may need to remove the account from the mail app or system preferences. A special case is iCloud where that is a toggle in the iCloud portion of system preferences.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/remove-email-accounts-mlhl9eb9408c/mac

To remediate your situation, disconnect from the internet and then remove the accounts as described above. The act of launching the app with a configured account is what triggers the download. Or you could use the mailbox menu and take all accounts offline.

Comment: My problem with the question is that not only is it zero research, it's also an xy problem. You can just switch the account off, don't even need to find/delete the login info.

Comment: @Tetsujin. No. deleting the login won't work. When I open Mail, it must ask me to import a message. I don't even get a chance to delete any account.

Comment: Where is it 'importing' messages from?

Comment: @bmike The 2nd link does not work for me. The "preference" is grayed out. For the first link, I don't want to delete everything in the keychain. But I don't see something specific to Mail.

Comment: @Tetsujin When I click an email address on a webpage, Mail starts automatically and start importing messages.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Where is it 'importing' messages from, not what triggers it?

Comment: I added the remediation steps @user1424739 we can’t guess how your Mac is set up from the scant details and research but we are sure in how to fix it - that is documented well by apple.

Comment: @Tetsujin  "importing" shows up when Mail is opened by click an email address on a webpage.